# PHP - Access Token no se me genera en Ubuntu/Linux pero sí en Windows

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Estoy trabajando con una API, la de Mercado Libre, usando el **php sdk** que ofrecen. Al código lo ejecuto utilizando **XAMPP**. Los access token, refresh token, etc se me generan correctamente en Windows. Pero el otro día probando en el s.o **Linux/Ubuntu**, el codigo php no me generaba el access token, nada, además, me dejaba la página index a la mitad (a partir de la linea donde comenzaba el php me ignoraba por completo sus funciones y etiquetas html que estaban fueras del php). El código es el mismo que utilizo en Windows, sin ninguna modificación.

Es mi primera vez usando Linux, asi que desconozco de este. La carpeta del sdk esta en var/www/html. Ya que me dijeron que tiene LAMP por defecto (no encontré su carpeta) El localhost  funcionaba ya que podia ingresar a él.  ¿Cual podria ser el error?
Gracias.